# std::transform is NOT analogous to std::for_each?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

In C++11, why is `std::for_each(lst.begin(), lst.end(), some_lambda);`

not the same as `std::transform(lst.begin(), lst.end(), lst.begin(), some_lambda);`?

The second one works, and the first one seems to do nothing. Am I overlooking something?

An example lambda:

```
auto some_lambda = [=] (std::string s) -> std::string {
  return "0" + s;
};
```

An example list:

```
std::list<std::string> lst; lst.push_back("");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one ignores the return value of the function. If you want to modify then use a reference as the function parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying a bit, `std::for_each` ends up something like this:

```
for (iter = start; iter != end; ++iter)
    f(*iter);
```

`std::ransform` is more like this:

```
for (iter = start; iter != end; ++iter, ++result)
    *result = f(*iter);
```

There is another variation of `transform`, but the general idea remains.

Note that `std::for_each` *does* return the function object after it's invoked on all the items in the range. Based on that, you *can* use it as a mediocre imitation of `std::accumulate`, by accumulating whatever you care about in the function object, and retrieving the accumulated value from it after it's returned.